# postgresql could not connect to server

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I've been trying to set up a VPS mainly for testing purposes, but I've lost so many hours now on this seemingly stupid issue that the only thing I can to is turn to the community's shared knowledge to try to solve it.

Scenario: Fresh VPS Ubuntu (Ubunut now) 12.04 install. Updated and upgraded.

First thing I do is to create a new user with sudo capabilities, login with such user and start working.
I input the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo su - postgres
psql -d postgres -U postgres
```

and now I get

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I am not a Linux wizard, but I've got a good experience in setting up a Rails/PG environment, I did it so many times on local machines, and a few times on VPS machines too.
Now, I just can't get what the hell is going on.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Ubuntu uses `pg_wrapper` and I'm pretty sure it creates a PostgreSQL database when Pg is installed. Are there any `postgres` processes running? What's in the PostgreSQL log files in `/var/log/postgresql`, if anything? BTW, your `sudo su - postgres` is totally unnecessary, you can just `sudo -u postgres psql`

Comment: Things to check: (a) Is Postgresql running? - `ps -e | grep postgres` (b) Is it running on port 5432? - `netstat -nlp | grep 5432` (c) What UNIX socket is Postgres listening on? - `netstat -lp --protocol=unix | grep postgres` (d) Can you connect over localhost? - `psql -U postgres -h localhost` [ while logged in to the shell as the postgres user ].

Comment: Trying to asnwer the best I can: 1) no result, 2) no result, 3) no result, 4) (No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=108 but you should be root.) if i run as root: psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432? ---- what sounds crazy to me, is that this is a clean install...

Comment: ps aux | grep postgre returns:          
root     11477  0.0  0.2   4100   840 pts/0    S+   14:51   0:00 grep --color=auto postgre

Comment: Why did you close the question?